# Visual Studio Bundler & Minifier - Remove important commands from CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio, minify, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using the VS Extension Bundler & Minifier from Mads Kristensen in the version 2.1.279.

I have a few of css files I bundled together and want them to minify. But I also want to remove important commands from the minified bundle.

The same works with javascript commands when using `"preserveImportantComments": false` in the minify options of the bundle in bundleconfig.json. But it seems, that this property is JS only.

My question: Is there an option to do the same with css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Using the `"commentMode": "none"` property for css files works and removes important commands.